# Taxonomy top level terms (plus other fields) in views block

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I have a term reference field on a content type. The vocabulary has two levels. I need to be able to show only the top level terms.

What is saved in the field:

```
X  Fruit
   X  Apple
   X  Orange
-  Veggie
   -  Carrot
   -  Green Bean
X  Candy
   -  Lollypop
   -  Chocolate
```

**What I want:**
Title: The Title
Categories: **Fruit, Candy**
Another Field: data

**What I get:**
Title: The Title
Categories: **Fruit, Apple, Orange, Candy**
Another Field: data

I am even fine with getting them all back but at least having the distinction what is top level so I can hide the others. I am trying to do this in a views block. I found answers on how to do this if I only wanted the terms, but I need more data from the node then that.

Answer (score 0):

After sucking up way to many hours on this project... I got it working by modifying the Hierarchical Term Formatter module: https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_term_formatter

By telling it to show only top level term, it would give me a list like this: **Fruit, Fruit, Fruit, Candy**

I went in and added a line to remove duplicate array values (using code I found here: [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php/)). I added it right about the return for hierarchical_term_formatter_field_formatter_view .

I now get the result I was looking for: **Fruit, Candy**

(PS I am not sure how I submit this to the creator of the module. I don't think it's necessarily a bug, but it could expand it's uses. I do not have experience in community coding projects.)